# Update a column where UniqueId is in a List<long> - with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a web api method that takes a List.  This list corepsonds to a list of Ids that are a unique key on a table.

I would like to do an update statement where the key is matched.  But I don't want to have to query out all those entities (and get hit with the materialization costs of that).

I know I can do this by making a User Defined Table Type and passing in the list to a stored procedure and run the update off of that.

**But I thought I would ask first, is this a common enough thing that Entity Framework can do this with out setting up a stored procedure?**

Comment: In short - no, EF is about operation with materialized objects.

Answer (score 1):

EF has no batch operations. You can try [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended):

```
context.Tasks
    .Where(t => list.Contains(t.Id))
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```